# try to send email message in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am New in asp.net .plz help

I am trying to send email message in C# with this code

can any body tell me what is wrong with my code ??..**it is building with out error but message didn't sent.**

```
 if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Request["SECURETOKENID"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Request["EMAIL"])) && (base.Request["RESPMSG"] == "Approved"))
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.GetConnectionString("DBConnect"));

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(string.Concat(new object[] { "UPDATE VIPPurchases SET PurchaseDate='", DateTime.Now, "', Status=1 WHERE PurchaseCode='", base.Request["SECURETOKENID"], "' AND Status=0" }), connection);

            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Ct.title, VI.VideoTitle FROM VIPView as VI INNER JOIN VIPPurchases as VP ON VI.catid = VP.VideoCode INNER JOIN categoryppv as Ct ON VP.VideoCode = Ct.catid WHERE VP.PurchaseCode='" + base.Request["SECURETOKENID"] + "' and VI.viewtype='3' AND VI.IsPublished='1'", connection);
                string str = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Value FROM Settings WHERE Name='Email'", connection);
                string addresses = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Fm.FilmmakerEmail, VI.VideoCode, VP.PurchaseCode FROM VIPPurchases as VP INNER JOIN VIPView as VI ON VP.VideoCode = VI.catid INNER JOIN Filmmakers as Fm ON VI.FilmmakerCode = Fm.FilmmakerCode where VP.PurchaseCode='" + base.Request["SECURETOKENID"] + "' and VI.viewtype='3' AND VI.IsPublished='1'", connection);
                addresses = addresses + ", " + ((string)command.ExecuteScalar());
                command = new SqlCommand("Select Value from Settings WHERE Name='SenderAddress'", connection);
                string userName = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                command = new SqlCommand("Select Value from Settings WHERE Name='SenderPassword'", connection);
                string password = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                command = new SqlCommand("Select Value from Settings WHERE Name='SMTP'", connection);
                string str5 = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                command = new SqlCommand("Select Value from Settings WHERE Name='Port'", connection);
                int num = Convert.ToInt32((string)command.ExecuteScalar());
                command = new SqlCommand("Select Value from Settings WHERE Name='SSL'", connection);

                bool flag = command.ExecuteScalar() == "True";

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Host = str5,
                    Port = Convert.ToInt32(num),
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password),
                    EnableSsl = flag
                };
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage
                {
                    Subject = "platformathletics World - Inndividual Registration",
                    From = new MailAddress(userName)
                };

                message.To.Add(base.Request["EMAIL"]);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = "<h3>platformathletics World - (" + str + ") Purchase</h3><p>You are allowed to watch training video <b>" + str + "</b> for next 30 days (till " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(30.0).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt") + "<sup style='color:red'>*</sup>) from now.</p><p>Your ticket number is <b>" + base.Request["SECURETOKENID"] + "</b>.</p><p>Put your ticket number <a href='http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + "/VIPMovieList.aspx'>here</a> in return box to watch the video.</p><p><a href='http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + "/login.aspx'>Login</a> or <a href='http:" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + "/register.aspx'>register</a> to platformathletics Network to manage your My Pay Per View Purchases section.</p><br /><hr><br /><small>You could be in different time zone other than United States but your ticket will expire in exact 30 days from the time you receive this email.</small>";
                client.Send(message);
                message = new MailMessage
                {
                    Subject = "platformathletics World - Inndividual Registration",
                    From = new MailAddress(userName)
                };
                message.To.Add(addresses);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Body = "<h3>platformathletics World - (" + str + ") Purchase</h3><p>Your video has been purchased. <i>" + base.Request["EMAIL"] + "</i> is allowed to watch <b>" + str + "</b> for 30 days.</p><p>Confirmation emails are also sent to " + base.Request["EMAIL"] + " and platformathletics Admin.";

                client.Send(message);
                this.ErrorPanel.Visible = false;
                this.SuccessPanel.Visible = true;
            }
```

Am I going on the right path??

Please help me..thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in try/catch?

Comment: Is there a run time Exception?

Comment: An unhandled exception would cause the program to crash. Is your program crashing? I also recommend wrapping your Send() calls in try/catch.

Comment: There can be a lot of things going wrong with email sending. Maybe your mail is sent, but you don't receive it because of a spam filter or any kind of filter on the mail server receiving it. Maybe the "to" address is wrong ? etc... this is of course in the case your code isn't crashing at runtime ! (compiling is just a syntax check, there's a lot of errors compilation won't get) as a side remark, I would advise not to make so many DB calls to get a few records... maybe group your settings by category ?

Comment: why I get -2 for my question???

Comment: You're getting negative scores because you're being a little too broad with your issue. You haven't made any attempt to diagnose the issue you're self and you haven't included any debug code. 

While the code itself is untidy and not well written, my guess and that's the best anyone can do for you, is that it's an issue with your HTML. That's assuming you're not getting any error messages or exceptions.

Again, due to the lack of information, I'm just shooting from the hip here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `try/catch` when you actually send the message, you'll get a more descriptiive message of what's going wrong:

```
try
{
      client.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      //Handle exception
      Console.Write(e.ToString()); //Or use another way to display the message.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
string mailServer;
int port;
string mailId, mailPass;
string subject;
string mailTo;
subject="something";
StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
mailTo = "someone@gmail.com";
mailServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
mailId = "something@gmail.com";
myString.Length = 0;
myString.Append("<html><body><div>BODY CONTENT</div></body></html>");
mailPass = "xxxxxx";
port = 587;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(mailId, mailTo, subject, myString.ToString());
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailServer, port);
System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailId, mailPass);
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = nc;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Change mailTo, mailId, mailPass according to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change :

```
this.ErrorPanel.Visible = false;
```

to

```
this.ErrorPanel.Visible = true;
```

See if that gives you an error.